Could anyone provide insights that clarify when this defense shines and when it might falter?
I've been studying various chess opening systems, and I've noticed that certain defenses, like the King's Indian Defense, can be incredibly effective at different levels of play. I’ve researched this, finding that some grandmasters swear by it, while others suggest it has weaknesses at the highest levels.
My question is: What makes the King's Indian Defense so resilient in certain situations, yet vulnerable in others? Specifically, I'm curious about how these dynamics change as one progresses from club-level play to elite grandmaster tournaments.

The King's Indian Defense (KID) has been around for decades, is continuously evolving, and has been the choice of elite players and world champions.
The general reputation among Masters (+2300 FIDE) is that it is objectively not the best defense but can lead to very complicated and sharp positions.
It is objectively not the best because White can take space advantage from the opening resulting in +0.6 of evaluation in engines like Stockfish.
Then why is it still played? Why did Alireza Firouzja play it almost exclusively during the SCC finals?
Because White play is far from easy with tactical complications and strategical nuances likely ensuing, and it has the potential for a king's side attack.
This blitz game between Hikaru and Alireza from two days ago well represents what I mean by tactical complications (although it later transposed into a Benoni):
[Title "Nakamura vs Firouzja, Speed Chess Championship 2024"]
[fen ""] 
[Startply "21"]
[Event "Speed Chess Championship 2024"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2024.09.03"]
[Round "03-01"] 
[White "Nakamura, Hikaru"] 
[Black "Firouzja, Alireza"]
[Result "1-0"]
[WhiteElo "3213"]
[BlackElo "3158"] 
[TimeControl "300+1"]
[Link "https://www.chess.com/events/2024-speed-chess-championship-main-event/03-01/Nakamura_Hikaru-Firouzja_Alireza"]

1. d4 {[%clk 0:05:00]} 1... Nf6 {[%clk 0:05:00]} 2. c4 {[%clk 0:04:59]} 
2... g6 {[%clk 0:05:00]} 3. f3 {[%clk 0:04:54]} 3... Bg7 {[%clk 0:05:00]} 
4. e4 {[%clk 0:04:54]} 4... d6 {[%clk 0:05:00]} 5. Nc3 {[%clk 0:04:54]} 5... O-O {[%clk 0:05:00]} 6. Bg5 {[%clk 0:04:54]}
6... c5 {[%clk 0:04:56]} 7. d5 {[%clk 0:04:53]} 7... a6 {[%clk 0:04:56]} 8. a4 {[%clk 0:04:51]} 8... e6 {[%clk 0:04:52]} 9. Qd2 {[%clk 0:04:51]} 9... exd5 {[%clk 0:04:51]} 10. cxd5 {[%clk 0:04:52]}
10... Nbd7 {[%clk 0:04:44]} 11. Nh3 {[%clk 0:04:40]} 11... Qa5 {[%clk 0:04:04]} 12. Ra3 {[%clk 0:04:37]} 12... Ne5 {[%clk 0:03:58]} 13. Nf2 {[%clk 0:04:37]} 13... Qb4 {[%clk 0:03:56]} 14. Qc2 {[%clk 0:03:38]}
14... Bd7 {[%clk 0:03:29]} 15. Bd2 {[%clk 0:03:35]} 15... Nc4 {[%clk 0:03:02]} 16. Rb3 {[%clk 0:02:35]} 16... Nxd2 {[%clk 0:03:01]} 17. Rxb4 {[%clk 0:02:36]} 17... cxb4 {[%clk 0:03:02]} 18. Qxd2 {[%clk 0:02:22]} 18... bxc3 {[%clk 0:03:02]} 19. bxc3 {[%clk 0:02:23]} 19... Bxa4 {[%clk 0:02:46]} 20. c4 {[%clk 0:02:23]} 20... Nd7 {[%clk 0:01:26]} 21. Qb4 {[%clk 0:02:00]} 21... Nc5 {[%clk 0:01:27]} 22. Nd3 {[%clk 0:01:50]} 22... a5 {[%clk 0:01:12]} 23. Qa3 {[%clk 0:01:48]}
23... Bd7 {[%clk 0:01:13]} 24. Nxc5 {[%clk 0:01:45]} 24... dxc5 {[%clk 0:01:14]} 25. Be2 {[%clk 0:01:27]} 25... Rfb8 {[%clk 0:00:59]} 26. Kf2 {[%clk 0:00:52]} 26... Bd4+ {[%clk 0:00:43]} 27. Kg3 {[%clk 0:00:51]}
27... b5 {[%clk 0:00:28]} 28. cxb5 {[%clk 0:00:52]} 28... Bxb5 {[%clk 0:00:28]} 29. Bxb5 {[%clk 0:00:50]} 29... Rxb5 {[%clk 0:00:29]} 30. Qa4 {[%clk 0:00:47]} 30... Rb4 {[%clk 0:00:18]} 31. Qc6 {[%clk 0:00:46]} 31... Rab8 {[%clk 0:00:18]} 32. Re1 {[%clk 0:00:25]} 32... R4b6 {[%clk 0:00:06]} 33. Qa4 {[%clk 0:00:22]} 33... Bc3 {[%clk 0:00:03]} 34. Re2 {[%clk 0:00:19]} 34... Rb4 {[%clk 0:00:03]} 35. Qc6 {[%clk 0:00:19]} 35... Be5+ {[%clk 0:00:03]} 36. Kh3 {[%clk 0:00:18]}
36... c4 {[%clk 0:00:03]} 37. g3 {[%clk 0:00:16]} 37... c3 {[%clk 0:00:02]} 38. f4 {[%clk 0:00:16]} 38... Rb2 {[%clk 0:00:02]} 39. Re1 {[%clk 0:00:10]} 39... Bd4 {[%clk 0:00:01]} 40. d6 {[%clk 0:00:11]}
40... c2 {[%clk 0:00:01]} 41. d7 {[%clk 0:00:11]} 41... Rb1 {[%clk 0:00:02]} 42. Qxc2 {[%clk 0:00:10]} 42... Rxe1 {[%clk 0:00:02]} 43. Qc8+ {[%clk 0:00:11]} 43... Rxc8 {[%clk 0:00:02]} 44. dxc8=Q+ {[%clk 0:00:11]} 44... Kg7 {[%clk 0:00:03]} 45. e5 {[%clk 0:00:10]} 45... Re2 {[%clk 0:00:03]} 46. Qc4 {[%clk 0:00:10]} 46... Rd2 {[%clk 0:00:03]}
47. Qc7 {[%clk 0:00:07]} 47... Bg1 {[%clk 0:00:03]} 48. e6 {[%clk 0:00:06]} 48... Rxh2+ {[%clk 0:00:03]} 49. Kg4 {[%clk 0:00:06]} 49... h5+ {[%clk 0:00:00]} 50. Kg5 {[%clk 0:00:05]} 1-0 

As you can see, Black sacrifices the queen for a material imbalance and to have the initiative in the queenside with the a and b pawns potentially marching. Although the engine again gives White the advantage after the sacrifice, inaccurate play followed and Black had chances to win.
This example is a classical attack on White's kingside in the KID when things go wrong for White:
[Event "World Team Championship"]
[fen ""] 
[Site "Bursa TUR"]
[Date "2010.01.09"]
[EventDate "2010.01.05"]
[Round "5"]
[Result "0-1"]
[White "Boris Gelfand"]
[Black "Hikaru Nakamura"]
[ECO "E97"]
[WhiteElo "2761"]
[BlackElo "2708"]
[PlyCount "66"]

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. e4 d6 5. Nf3 O-O 6. Be2 e5
7. O-O Nc6 8. d5 Ne7 9. Nd2 Ne8 10. b4 f5 11. c5 Nf6 12. f3 f4
13. Nc4 g5 14. a4 Ng6 15. Ba3 Rf7 16. b5 dxc5 17. Bxc5 h5
18. a5 g4 19. b6 g3 20. Kh1 Bf8 21. d6 axb6 22. Bg1 Nh4
23. Re1 Nxg2 24. dxc7 Nxe1 25. Qxe1 g2+ 26. Kxg2 Rg7+ 27. Kh1
Bh3 28. Bf1 Qd3 29. Nxe5 Bxf1 30. Qxf1 Qxc3 31. Rc1 Qxe5
32. c8=Q Rxc8 33. Rxc8 Qe6 0-1

Here I am showing what any KID player dreams of, there are hundreds of games where Black loses without the chance to complicate but that's less fun to show ;)
In summary, the KID is a risky defense that may give many practical chances if Black knows the theory, is familiar with the main tactical ideas, and is ready to get into complicated lines to fight for the initiative. This style may suit anybody at any level. The risk to get crushed in classical chess by a combination of engine prep plus accurate play increases with White's strength but it is still a popular choice among beginners and strong amateur players.

Interesting, thanks for you answer! Now I got it pretty much better than before

The KID is used by strong grandmasters and still is used by the elite of correspondence chess, however lately, there has been a shift towards other defenses. Nevertheless, the KID is a very sound defence.
Chess Engines still have a hard time assessing typical KID-structures correctly, but after long analysis, the assessment mostly comes to 0.0 .
Vulnerability: You need to know a lot of theory with black, white can really choose his setup and you need to know an answer for everything
Resiliency: the KID is not resilient, you play the KID in order to attack and  win.
And for your last question: It is always a good choice against weaker players.
I am not an elite grandmaster, just a FM, but the dynamics never really changed. Against GMs i actually drew all my games so far, but they always tried a very positional approach against me.
